# Solving a system of linear equation with pseudoinverse

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

What theorem would you use to solve the following problem?

Denote by $h$ the solution to the linear system: $Ah=b$. For solving, we try the iteration  $x_{n+1} = x_n + \eta_nA^Tr_n$, where for the $n$-th iterate $x_n$, the residual is $r_n=b-Ax_n$ and the scalar  $\eta_n$ is sought such that $\left \| x_{n+1}-h \right \|_2$ is minimal. Find the formula for $\eta_n$ with the aid of the pseudoinverse!

Answer (score 0):

So we simply do some algebra

$$\min_{\eta_n} || x_{n+1} - h||_2^2 =  \min_{\eta_n} ||x_n + \eta_n A^\top(b-Ax_n)-h||^2$$

taking derivative w.r.t. to $\eta_n$ we get:

$$  (x_n^\top + \eta_n (b^\top - x_n^\top A^\top)A - h^\top)(A^\top b - Ax_n) = 0 $$

$$\eta_n = \frac{(x_n^\top  - h^\top)(A^\top b - Ax_n)}{(b^\top - x_n^\top A^\top)A(A^\top b - Ax_n)}$$

solving this equation and using that $h = (A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top b$ yields the result.

Answer (score 0):

**That theorem you probably want to use:** If $B$ has full column rank then the linear least squares problem "find $y$ such that $\|By-c\|_2$ is minimal" has a unique solution given by $y=B^+c$.

In your problem, if you write $\|x_{n+1}-h\|_2$ as 
$$
\|x_{n+1}-h\|_2=\|x_n+\eta_nA^Tr_n-h\|_2=\|(A^Tr_n)\eta_n-(h-x_n)\|_2,
$$
you can find out that $c=h-x_n$ and $B=A^Tr_n$. Assuming $A^Tr_n\neq 0$ (a nonzero column vector has certainly full column rank), we have
$$
\eta_n=(A^Tr_n)^+(h-x_n).
$$
Note that for a nonzero column vector $d$, its pseudo-inverse is $d^+=d^T/\|d\|_2^2$. So
$$
\eta_n=\frac{r_n^TA(h-x_n)}{\|A^Tr_n\|_2^2}=\frac{r_n^Tr_n}{(A^Tr_n)^T(A^Tr_n)}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.